# Page doesn't load after new class instance (PHP)

Tags: php, class, instance

I created a site within Xampp and everything works great.  However, when I upload the site to server, creating a new class kills the rest of the page.

Example - PHP code:

```
echo 'Code before instance is created';

$instance = new fooClass();

echo 'Nothing runs after instance is created';
```

Result on page:

Code before instance is created

Error_log:
Shows no errors.
Server: Bluehost

Comment: r u sure your error_log works correctly ?

Comment: add 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
before the new instance and check for error maybe you error_log dosent work correctly

Comment: Thanks for quick response.  Been working on ever since and finally got up and running.  Thanks again.